# sails + socket + angular issue with header i socket requests

Tags: angularjs, node.js, sockets, sails.js

I'm a real beginner on Angular and is following this example:
https://github.com/balderdashy/angularSails/blob/master/example/assets/js/app.js

The issue i have is that i want to add a header to all request so i can pass a token,
So i want to add a Authorization header.
I have looked on the documentation on ngsails:
http://balderdashy.github.io/angularSails/#/api/ngsails.$sailsSocket

But can get it to work. Anyone that have a ide how to get it to work with the example above?